# Role in JBoss 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

Beside having some roles from database (using org.jboss.security.mapping.providers.role.DatabaseRolesMappingProvider), I would like to assign some fixed role for all authenticated user. How could I achieve that in JBoss 7?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make authentication with basic or digest method. Here the guide:
[http://docs.jboss.org/exojcr/1.14.7-GA/developer/en-US/html/ch82.html

Comment: do you stil need support?